# Adding two Integers to array index without summing them

Tags: c#, integer, char

I'm a beginner in C# , 
I'm trying to do this ..... user input "43 24" and the application take this input , put 43 in arr1[0] , and 24 in arr1[1] . The arr1 is char[] type .. i tried this : (This is only a part of the code of course) (wholeLine is type string)

```
foreach (char ch in wholeLine)
      {
          if (ch != ' ')
              {                     
                 arr1[0]  += ch ;                     
              }
      }
```

and the output for arr[0] is : `g`

I tried to make arr1 an int[] type and did this :

```
foreach (char ch in wholeLine)
      {
          if (ch != ' ')
              {
                 int z = Convert.ToInt32(ch.ToString());
                 arr1[0]  += z ;                     
              }
      }
```

But the output is : `7`

I just want arr[0] to contain `43` , i think it's a conversions issue , but i have no clue what to do , so help please :)

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a string array. If you call [`.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on your string, it will return an array of strings:

```
string words = "This is a list of words, with: a bit of punctuation" +
                   "\tand a tab character.";

string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });

foreach (string s in split) {

    if (s.Trim() != "")
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use wholeLine.Split(" ") which will split your string and make string[] array out of it.

Comment: Where is the Split(...) that takes a single string, rather than an array (of strings or chars)?  Not a slating - I suggested the same and edited my comment shortly afterwards.  There really should be a good old plain Split(string delim)!

Comment: and i mistyped because of keyboard, i don't really care anyway. the way it is my answer is wrong anyway even though it was first.

Answer (score 0):

Try `string[] arr1 = wholeLine.Split(new char[] {' '});`